# What do hams mean when they refer to "higher bands"

Tags: jargon

For example, the [Ultimate3S kit info](http://www.qrp-labs.com/ultimate3/u3s.html) page says:

> Produces 250mW RF output on 30m (lower output on higher bands)

Would bands "higher" than 30m mean:

- bands with higher *frequency* e.g. 20m/17m/15m?
- bands with higher *wavelength* e.g. 40m/80m/160m?

It seems like an ambiguous way to refer to the "height" of a *band* rather than either its frequency or wavelength directly, so whenever I see this usage I am uncertain.

Comment: In the olde days the 160meter band was called "Top Band"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *this* case, they probably mean higher frequency. Two pieces of evidence:

- One typically says “**longer/shorter** wavelength”, not “higher/lower wavelength”.
- Lower power output at higher frequencies is common, because components' and circuits' characteristics are generally worse at higher frequencies.

But there are also opposite terms, like “top band” for 160 meters.

I would personally avoid saying things like “higher bands” exactly because of this ambiguity; perhaps instead “higher-frequency bands”.

Comment: In the olde days when I was thin and had thick hair 160 meters was called "Top Band"

Comment: Thanks, and welcome @Autistic! I've still seen 160m called that (albeit many of my radio books are older themselves) as well as plenty of variation on usage of various terms. We'll see what happens in the ARRL documentation if the FCC opens the [2200m band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2200-meter_band) — which you might already have acess to in New Zealand :-) Looks like Kevin already does have this special name for 160m in his answer.